# How can I get attribute in svg class

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the attribute in a svg class but it doesn't work.

I am using Django, html, php, query.

```
    <svg:path id="yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1556774865622_2128" 
pointer-events="visiblePainted" shape-rendering="auto" width="206" height="267.5" x="0" y="0" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="none" 
stroke="#27aae1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linejoin="round" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)" style="left: 0px;
 top: 0px; visibility: visible;"
 class="yui3-shape yui3-svgShape yui3-path yui3-svgPath" 
d=" M103, 267.5C154.5,267.5 206, 228 206, 188.5">
</svg:path>
```

I tried the following, but it does not work.

```
$(".yui3-shape yui3-svgShape yui3-path yui3-svgPath").each(function(index, item){
        let temp = $(item).attr('s');
        console.log("edge"+temp);
    });
```

Comment: What "does not work"?

Comment: `.yui3-shape yui3-svgShape yui3-path yui3-svgPath` selector will search for a `<yui3-svgPath>` element inside a `<yui-3-path>` element inside a `<yui3-svgShape>` element inside an element with the class `yui3-shape`. I guess you wanted `.yui3-shape.yui3-svgShape.yui3-path.yui3-svgPath` which will search for an element with all these classes.

Comment: not work mean is console.log result is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You selected the wrong selectors. If you are selecting multiple classes from one selector then you have to add them like this: `.yui3-shape.yui3-svgShape.yui3-path.yui3-svgPath`

Additionally, you should add the proper name of the attribute:

```
$(".yui3-shape.yui3-svgShape.yui3-path.yui3-svgPath").each(function(index, item){
    let temp = $(item).attr('stroke'); // Here you can add attributename as per your requierments
    console.log("edge "+temp);
});
```